# IPC between C# and C++. (NOT NAMED PIPES)

Tags: c#, c++, pipe, ipc

I have parent process (c++ code) and child process (c# code). In parent I open pipe with fd = 199 for reading, then I want to write in this pipe in C#, how should I do this?

I did this:

```
var w = new BinaryWriter(new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, "199")
```

and got this:

```
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Bad file descriptor
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.CheckPipeCall(Int32 result)
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.ValidateHandleIsPipe(SafePipeHandle safePipeHandle)
   at System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream.Init(PipeDirection direction, SafePipeHandle safePipeHandle)
   at System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream..ctor(PipeDirection direction, String pipeHandleAsString)
```

Comment: and i use linux

Comment: Well if it's anonymous how do you propose the other process finds it? Perhaps pass the pipe handle as a command-line parameter. Why can't you use a named pipe?

Comment: @Charlieface I know descriptor, it is 199. I want to know what the problem is with anonymous pipe:)

Comment: Where did you find documentation that the string value expected is just the file descriptor number? [The code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Pipes/src/System/IO/Pipes/AnonymousPipeClientStream.cs#L29-L37) expects a stringified pointer value.

Comment: I'm probably missing something here. Your parent process has a FD of 199. That's the FD **in the parent process**. What have you done that makes you believe the child process also has the same file descriptor with the same number referring to the same pipe?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct formulation here ought to be:

```cs
var w = new BinaryWriter(new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, new SafePipeHandle(new IntPtr(199), true))
```

Comment: almost the same error:

Comment: ```Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
---> System.IO.IOException: Bad file descriptor
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.CheckPipeCall(Int32 result)
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.ValidateHandleIsPipe(SafePipeHandle safePipeHandle)
   at System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream..ctor(PipeDirection direction, SafePipeHandle safePipeHandle)
```

Comment: Then we have to see the code of the parent process. Please edit your post

Comment: It was my mistake in C++ code, I closed correct side of pipe. Thank you for your help! You saved me